# Symfony sensio/framework-extra-bundle is abandoned, what #[Security] alternative?

Tags: symfony, security, routes, components, bundle

I saw "Package `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use Symfony instead."

but I use it in my Controller :

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

#[Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER') and user === choosenUser")]

#[Route('/movement/user/{id}', name: 'app_movement_user')]
public function.......
```

What I have to use now to keep Security ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From Symfony 6.2, you can use native attribute #[IsGranted] with expressions.

Replace #[Security] by :

```
//use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\IsGranted;
    
#[IsGranted(
   new Expression('is_granted("ROLE_USER") and user== ...')
)]
#[Route('/movement/user/{id}', name: 'app_movement_user')]
```

Sources :

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-built-in-cache-security-template-and-doctrine-attributes

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#access-control-authorization

Discussion in Symfony gitHub :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/48878

Using Expressions in Security Access Controls :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/expressions.html

Take time to find and read documentation. :)

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down, but this answer has absolutely saved me. Thank you!

Comment: thank you @Mick3DIY - just the link to the GitHub issue... ugh :)

Comment: @craigh Yes, it's always interesting to have the whole process of a problem... Cheers !